# Automate end-snap of lines mid-way between nodes?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, arcpad, trimble

I have a polyline feature class of field-collected (Trimble GeoXT with ArcPad10) stream segments.  For whatever reason (still troubleshooting why), my employee returned from the field and the majority of the endpoints were not snapped (despite occurring within distances of the snapping distance I'd specified on the XT).

To automate generation of a continuous series of stream segments, I already ran the "Snap" tool, but it only moved one endpoint and left the other one fixed.  In this scenario, I cannot assume that one end-point is more accurate than the other, so I would like to average them.

Is there a command (or maybe an environment setting within "Snap") I'm missing that would move endpoints for adjacent lines and snap them half-way along a straightline distance in between?

Alternatively, a command that generates a point midway between ends that I could subsequently snap lines to would probably work as well.

I have an ArcInfo license v10 SP4.

Thanks,
Will